# Get checkbox value from grails controller

Tags: javascript, html, grails, groovy, gsp

I have a grails project where I need to select the fields that I want to delete and when I click 'delete' I need a function to delete all selected items:

**html code:**

```
<form name="bookForm" action="list" method="post">
    ....
    <g:link controller="book" action="delete">Delete</g:link>
    ....
    ....
    <g:checkBox id="select_all" name="select_all" value="" onclick="selectAll();" />
    ....
    <g:each in="${bookList}" status="i" var="bookInstance">
        <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'odd' : 'even'}">
            <td><g:checkBox id="${bookInstance.id}" name="delete_checkbox" value="" /></td>
        </tr>
    </g:each>
    ....
</form>
```

**javascript code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function selectAll(){//this function is used to check or uncheck all checkboxes
        var select = document.getElementById("select_all");
        var checkboxes = document.forms['bookForm'].elements['delete_checkbox'];
        if (select.checked){
            for (i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) checkboxes[i].checked = true;
        }else{
            for (i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) checkboxes[i].checked = false;
        }
    }//this function works fine
</script>
```

**Problem:**

I need the action to check all checkboxes in the list gsp, and if they are checked, take their ids and delete the record by id.

Can i do that either by groovy or javascript?

Comment: This is a grails question, not a groovy question

Comment: but the code i must write it in the controller to solve my problem  is groovy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite your checkbox like:

```
<g:checkBox id="delete_checkbox" name="delete_checkbox" value="${bookInstance.id}" />
```

So, when you submit, you'll get an array of ids called **_delete_checkbox** or **delete_checkbox** inside your **params** map. To see what you're getting you can try printing your params inside the action.

```
println params
```

You can get the desired array by using `params['nameOfTheAttribute']`.
Once you have the array of ids, iterate over it and delete them all.

Comment: when i write println params.delete_checkbox or println params it returns null

Comment: What?? println params returns null? Weird. If you create an input with a value, say 2, it shows on params?

Comment: i must change the g:link to button to submit the form. after this change, your answer is true. thanks `Tiago Farias`

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you set value for checkbox = "". That's incorrect, because value is what get submitted to server.

You need to change it as the following:

```
        <td><g:checkBox id="${bookInstance.id}" name="delete_checkbox" value="${bookInstance.id}"" /></td>
```